# breakpoints in SharpDevelop with IronPython

Tags: .net, winforms, ide, ironpython, sharpdevelop

is it possible somehow to get the breakpoints to work in SharpDevelop with IronPython/Winforms? They work alright with other languages but with IronPython they just don't stop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Breakpoints will work in SharpDevelop 3.2 if you run your application with the IronPython Console (ipy.exe) via the menu option Python | Run. Breakpoints will not work if you run your application with the debugger via the menu option Debug | Run. This is because the compiler does not generate debugging symbols.

You will also need to make sure that the Just My Code option is enabled in the debugger as shown in [Debugging IronPython in SharpDevelop](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/mattward/archive/2009/05/30/DebuggingIronPythonCode.aspx).

If you are using SharpDevelop 4 beta 1 currently breakpoints do not work at all.

Comment: are they also supposed to work when developing a Windows application , or that way to run them is only for class library or console application? Because in the way you mentioned they also dont work for me when developing a Windows application

Comment: They should work for any sort of application, WinForms or Console.